# Congruence Property of Monotone Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis, monotone-operator-theory

A map $T$ is called strictly monotone if for $x\ne y$, $\langle u-v,x-y\rangle>0$ for all $u\in T(x),v\in T(y)$.

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $b\in\mathbb R^m$. I want to prove that if $T:\mathbb R^n\rightrightarrows\mathbb R^m$ is strictly monotone and $\text{rank}\;A=n$, then $S:=A^TT(Ax+b)$ is also strictly monotone.

Let $u\in S(x)$ and $v\in S(y)$, then we have
$$u=A^Tu',v=A^Tv',u'\in T(Ax+b),v'\in T(Ay+b)$$
and
$$\langle u-v,x-y\rangle=\langle A^Tu'-A^Tv',x-y\rangle=\langle u'-v',Ax-Ay\rangle=\langle u'-v',Ax+b-(Ay+b)\rangle>0$$
since $T$ was strictly monotone and if $x\ne y$ then $Ax+b\ne Ay+b$, but I don't know why the condition that  $\text{rank}\;A=n$ is necessary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $rank(A) < n$, the strictness of $S$ may be lost, since it is now possible that $x \ne y$ but $S(x) \cap S(y) \ne \emptyset$. That is because there is $w \ne 0$ such that $Aw = 0$. You should be able to construct a counterexample to strict monotonicity using that information.

Comment: Thanks, Do you say that if $x\ne y$, then it is possible that $Ax+b=Ay+b$?

Comment: More precisely, there are $x \ne y$ such that $Ax = Ay$, if $A$ does not have full rank.